# How to open a dialog in modal-mode

Tags: xul, thunderbird

What's the correct method, to open up a new dialog so that the user cannot return to the main window until the modal dialog is closed.

A typical modal window is created by the alert() function.

I've tried it like this without success:

```
.openWindow(null, "chrome://myapp/content/mywindow.xul","mywindow", 
"chrome,centerscreen,all,modal",null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to mention that you are using [nsIWindowWatcher](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsIWindowWatcher#openWindow%28%29).

For the window to be modal you need to specify which window it needs to be modal to. If the first parameter to your `openWindow()` call is `null` then the window watcher won't know which window opened the dialog (which window needs to be suspended until the dialog is closed). In other words:

```js
watcher.openWindow(mainWin, "chrome://myapp/content/mywindow.xul", "mywindow",
                   "chrome,centerscreen,all,modal", null);
```

Or simpler:

```js
mainWin.openWindow("chrome://myapp/content/mywindow.xul", "mywindow",
                   "chrome,centerscreen,all,modal");
```

See [window.openDialog()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.openDialog).

Comment: thank you again, Wladimir ! But when I define the `mainWin` variable as `"chrome://messenger/content/AccountManager.xul"` it results in a error-message (console)

Comment: If you don't have a reference to the window already, you can use [nsIWindowMediator.getMostRecentWindow()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsIWindowMediator#getMostRecentWindow%28%29) to find it (window type being `"mailnews:accountmanager"` in this case).